# WMS position not identical in QGIS data and print view

Tags: qgis, wms, printing

I have a WMS layer with the same CRS as the other layers in QGIS. In the normal map view the position of the WMS layer is correct:

[image]

But in any print layout the blue and red areas of the WMS are not in the same positions. This happens in QGIS and LizMap (which sits on top of QGIS Server).

[image]

The shift looks like a wrong transformation but the WMS is available in the same CRS as the rest of my layers. I can't replicate this behaviour in ArcMap.

What is this problem and how can I fix it?

WMS: https://www.geoportal.hessen.de/mapbender/php/mod_showMetadata.php/../wms.php?layer_id=47243&PHPSESSID=9d63788jiatpdaoi6vc7qhd9c2&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS&withChilds=1

Comment: Please provide your export settings, as well as the WMS.

Comment: I added the WMS in my question. What exactly are these export settings? The difference is already visible in the layout preview window of a completely new layout in a completely new project of a completely fresh installation.